# Как запустить программу на определенное время?

Tags: c++, c, время

Мне нужно,чтобы программа отработала ровно 30 секунд?
Как такое реализовать на с++/с

```
int main()
{
    int start = clock(); // засекаем время старта
    // далее фрагмент кода, время работы которого измеряется
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            cout<<"a";
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    int end = clock(); // засекаем время окончания
    int t = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;// команда CLOCKS_PER_SEC нужна для перевода результата функции clock в секунды

    cout<<" "<<t; // вывод результата работы на экран
}
```

при такой реализации выводится 0.
Может можно сделать как-то по-другому?

Comment: Формулировка вопроса в заголовке некорректна. Исправьте её, чтобы она правильно отражала суть вопроса.

Comment: В заголовке одно, в коде другое... Что должна делать программа 30 секунд? Просто ждать? так поместите три последние строчки в цикл и ждите, пока t не станет равным 30...

Comment: @Harry ждать в цикле? Так себе предложение. Рациональнее будет использовать `sleep_for`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так ведь какой вопрос, такой и ответ :) В вопросе - чтоб программа **работала**, а не ожидала :)

Answer (score 0):

0 у Вас выводится из-за того, что выполнение программы занимает менее одной секунды, то есть число при делении на `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` получается дробное. А Вы его присваиваете переменной типа `int`, которая представляет целое число. В результате производится округление до целого и получается 0. Чтобы исправить ситуацию, необходимо использовать переменную дробного типа, а также привести к дробному типу переменные, содержащие начальную и конечную метки времени:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int start = clock(); // засекаем время старта
    // далее фрагмент кода, время работы которого измеряется
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            cout<<"a";
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    int end = clock(); // засекаем время окончания
    double t = (static_cast<double>(end) - static_cast<double>(start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;// команда CLOCKS_PER_SEC нужна для перевода результата функции clock в секунды

    cout<<" "<<t; // вывод результата работы на экран
}
```

На всякий случай поясню: `static_cast<тип 2>(переменная типа 1)` используется для приведения типа переменной из типа 1 в тип 2. Это аналогично `(тип 2)переменная типа 1` в "чистом" Си (который без ++).

Теперь программа будет выводить дробное число, показывающее сколько секунд заняло выполнение цикла с выводом.